# Order View missing buttons

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, ce-1.9.2.2

I have my first orders (all sold with **PayPal**) but in the order view there are no buttons for invoice, ship or reorder. I cant figure out what's wrong. `/app/core/` hasn't been changed.

Do you have an idea?

**EDIT**

I found out that if an order is on "pending payment" all buttons are shown.

**EDIT 2**

In the sales_flat_order-table is state on 'payment_review',but it has to be processing.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your account has sufficient permissions to do those actions.

If you have a user that is an administrator you should be able to see everything however if your account is in a custom role you may not have permissions.

These are set in System > Users > Roles

Then you can edit the roles to include/exclude actions:
[image]

Comment: ty for your fast response. I have Rescource Access: All

Comment: Does the order have a notification in the Order History section saying the IPN notification has been received. It could be that the IPN has failed so the order is still in a pending payment status.

Comment: it says IPN "Completed"

Comment: Do you have any modules that could potentially be overriding the buttons and also is there anything relevant to the admin page in the system.log or exception.log?

Answer (score 0):

All of our custom developed modules are stored in the app/code/local folder. If in case an error has not been logged in error log files and to troubleshoot we want to check whether one of our custom modules is causing problems or not, so in that case we should first disable all local modules and see if the site is working or not.

To disable all the local modules:

1. Open the app/etc/local.xml file and locate “disable_local_modules” xml tag

false

2. Change the <disable_local_modules> xml tag to true
   <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
3. Clear the Magento Cache

Now test the website. If the error goes away, it means one of your custom modules is causing problem. You now need to disable individual modules and check to find the culprit module.